# View not rendering when redirected programmatically - Reactjs Connected Router

Tags: reactjs

When the user token is available in local storage and the "/login" url is taken on browser,then the user should be redirected to the dashboard page.

So the code is written as follows.

```
const history = createHistory();
const { token, location } = this.props;
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" render={ () => (token && <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>) || <Login />}
    />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  </Switch>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Dashboard component is written as follows.

```
class Dashboard extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dashboard-wrapper">
          This is a dashboard view
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Package.json dependencies

```
    "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

The problem is that, dashboard view is not rendering when redirected from the login page.

Current behaviour -

- When '/login' is typed in, it should redirect to '/dashboard' -
  Working now '
- '**This is a dashboard view**' text to render when redirected to the dashboard page - Not working

Expected behaviour
 - '**This is a dashboard view**' text to render when redirected to the dashboard page

Any idea on how to fix this.

EDIT 1:

If i use browser router instead of connected router, the above code is working fine.

But i need to know what is the issue when using connected router.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to define the props as an argument in render prop functional component

```
const history = createHistory();
const { token, location } = this.props;
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" render={ (props) => (token && <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>) || <Login {...props}/>}
    />
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  </Switch>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Added the code <Route path="/login" render={ (props) => (token && <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>) || <Login {...props}/>}
    />. But still having the same issue